# MYSQL IN statement

Tags: mysql, database

Im using `IN` to select stuff...

```
WHERE categories IN ("red", "blue", "green")
```

This selects any item in red, blue or green categories, my question is, is there a way to select an item that has to be in all three categories?

Comment: Is categories a column in a table? How would multiple categories be represented in it if so?

Comment: @DavidM Yeah, I realized that too when typing out an answer.  If it's a single column (like the asker suggested with the partial query), how could it belong to multiple categories?

Comment: @Crontab Especially with the `WHERE column IN ()`.

Comment: categories is a column in a table with multple categories being represented via multiple rows

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
SELECT Item
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE categories IN ('red', 'blue', 'green')
    GROUP BY Item
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT categories) = 3
```

Comment: how do you add limit? 

this one is definitely wrong SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE City IN ('Berlin', 'México D.F.') LIMIT 5, 5;

Comment: @MarlonBuendia Please start a new question for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Item
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE categories ALL ('red', 'blue', 'green')
```