# mysqli get something WHERE

Tags: mysqli

So I only want to get items from userSubscriptionLevel WHERE the id is anything but 4 or 6.  What's the best way to give this exclusions?

```
function getUserLevelMapping() {
    global $mysqli;

    $userLevels =  $mysqli->get('userSubscriptionLevel');
    $userLevelMapping = array();
    foreach($userLevels as $userLevel) {
            $userLevelMapping[$userLevel['code']] = $userLevel['id'] ;
    }

    return $userLevelMapping;
}
```

Comment: Look at mysql docs for `NOT IN` - would look like `WHERE userSubscriptionLevel NOT IN(4, 6)`

Comment: THANK YOU!  If you want to post that as an answer I'll mark it as correct and give you the credit.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [IN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837584/mysql-in-statement) and `NOT IN` - both super useful methods for looking for (or excluding) specific records.

In your case, a `NOT IN` query is what you want, and it would look like so:

```
Select ... WHERE userSubscriptionLevel NOT IN(4, 6)
```

(query all records excluding userSubscriptionLevel that is 4 or 6)