# MYSQL Query to find an element of an Array

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I have a column where data is saved in the following syntax:

```
Value1;Value2;Value3
```

I have an array and I would like to check if any of the elements contain a value in the table. I read a little bit and found that the SQL Query:"WHERE...IN.. should do this but I havent done it successfully right now. Here is my command:

```
db.query(

'SELECT * FROM blocklist WHERE BanContent IN ?', [inputarray.join(",")],
function (err, results) {
    try {

        console.log(results)

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

});
```

I allways get undefined as the result.

Comment: `IN` requires the values it should check for to be in parenthesis.

Comment: Can i give you example of PHP PDO Query? but i think you are using Console? im not familiar with console.

Comment: "select * from `blocklist` where `BanContent` IN ", [inputarray.join(",")],
function (err, results)

Comment: Where did you read that IN could do this?

Comment: Why not, maybe it helps. @waka is there a sql query which work the way I need it or do i need to for loop every array element. Would not be the worst case since the array I want to check is not that big.

Comment: [Have a look at an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8837618/2099119)

Comment: @waka That's a different situation.

Comment: @Strawberry: But still shows how to use `IN` correctly, which the OP doesn't, in my opinion. Or maybe I'm too tired right now and miss the obvious.

Comment: IN cannot do this nor does mysql have a split function. You best do it as you suggest. Although there are plenty of answers in SO for splitting strings it would probably be quicker for you to do it the way you know.

Comment: @waka IN ain't going to help here; not without some structural changes anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET('v2',REPLACE('v1;v2;v3',';',','))x;
+---+
| x |
+---+
| 2 |
+---+
```

And now see about normalisation and why it's a bad idea to store delimited data in an RDBMS.